# Jquery flip stops working after recalling function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main function and I am recalling it with other values after a click on a menu. After that action (click on menu button) my #card stops flipping on click. it seems like I am removing event handler or sth in wrong place, but I have no idea where..

the html is simple. there is a card div:

```
<div id="card">

  <div class="front">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <h2>Ups</h2>
    <p>Nic tu nie ma!<br>:(</p>
  </div>

  <div class="back">
    <p>:(</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

And the menu div:

```
<div class="navigation" style="display: none;">
<ul>
  <li class="first-menu navigation-item">(...)</li>

  <li class="second-menu navigation-item">(...)</li>

  <li class="list-words navigation-item">(...)</li>

  <li class="shuffle navigation-item">(...)</li>

  <li class="reverse-cards navigation-item">(...)</li>

  <li class="start-quiz navigation-item">(...)</li>

  <li class="return navigation-item"></li>
</ul>
```

Now, the js.

There is a navigate() function, which shows and hides the menu, and allows user to turn back to the "first menu", which means, turn back to the choose of main chapter.

Never mind, I mean that there are three menus. two of them causes an ajax call and show the flash-card with chosen words. I have problem with third menu, (on the right top corner of page). this menu should let user mix the flash-cards, reverse it, navigate etc. The problem occures after a click on each item in this menu.

[this picture shows items on this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIFiH.png)

[this picture shows the #card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFLit.png)

Before the click, the main card flips without problem.
but when you mix the words, or click other menu item, it stops flipping on click.

Ok, now the code:

this is the main function which let user change words on #card, mix them etc.

```
function main(){

(...)

$('.second-menu').click(function () { //turn back to the second menu
  $('#main-container > div:not(.title-div, .list-icon)').fadeOut(0);
  $('.navigation').fadeOut(0); //.navigation -> this is the third menu
  $('.menu2').fadeIn(0);
});

$('.list-words').click(function () { //this allows to change the view
  $('#main-container > div:not(.title-div, .list-icon)').fadeOut(0);

  $('.list-words-tiles > li').remove();
  $('.navigation').fadeOut(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(responceData).length; ++i) {
    $('.list-words-tiles').append('<li class="words"> <div class="front"><div>' + responceData[i].q + '</div></div><div class="back"><div>' + responceData[i].a + '</div></div></li>');
  }
  $('.list').css("display", "flex");

  $('.words').off('flip').flip({ //maby here??
    "forceHeight": true,
    "forceWidth": true
  });
  $(this).click(function () {
    $('.list').fadeOut(0);
    $('#card').fadeIn(0);
    main(responceData, reverse);
    return;
  });
}); //here the "other view" ends

$('.shuffle').click(function () { //mixing the words
  $('.navigation').fadeOut(0);
  main(shuffle(responceData), reverse);
  return;
});

$('.reverse-cards').click(function () { //reversing
  $('.navigation').fadeOut(0);
  main(responceData, !reverse);
  return;
});

}
```

And in the document.ready I have a flip handler:

```
$('#card').off('flip').flip({
"speed": "600",
"forceHeight": "100%"
});
```

As you can see, on each "third menu" item click, the main function is recalled to introduce changes, (show mixed or reverse words starting with first element in array).

So why does flip stop working after that actions?

Here you can see the issue: [link](http://fiszki.janek.ovh)

Comment: i think it would be nice if you can format and segregate the html and the js part of your code so that someone can isolate your problem into smaller parts. From the link you have shared it is difficult to make out what breaks and what works!

Comment: ok, i will try.

Comment: the strange thing is, that when you open the site at mobile phone or with chrome dev tool set to "responsive", it all works fine.